# Issue building string in for loop

Tags: javascript, html, json

Im having trouble figuring why I'm not able to build a string by adding other in a loop. Heres the JavaScript function:

```
function displayCountries(){
    var body = "<option value='select'>...</option>";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        for (var i=0;i < data.length;i++) {
            body +="<option value='" + data[i].name + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>";
            console.log("<option value='" + data[i].name + "'>" + data[i].name + "</option>");

        }
    }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
    xhr.send(null);
    console.log(body);
    document.getElementById("country-select").innerHTML=body;
}
```

The first console log works out fine printing the data as I expect and to see if I had no syntax errors passing to html, but the **body** variable doesent add the string in the loop so the second log only prints out the option "...".

Ive read through this a couple this but cant figure out why this isnt working. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting the `innerHTML` property way before the response is available.

I will suggest you to create an *option* element and append that inside the for loop:

```js
function displayCountries(){
  var select = document.getElementById("country-select");
  select.innerHTML = "<option value='select'>...</option>";

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.withCredentials = false;

  xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
      var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      for (var i = 0;i < data.length; i++) {
        var o = document.createElement('option');
        o.value = data[i].name;
        o.text = data[i].name;
        select.appendChild(o);
      }
    }
  });

  xhr.open("GET", "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all?fields=name;");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/json");
  xhr.send(null);
}
displayCountries();
```

```html
<select id="country-select"></select>
```